# Codeigniter Grocery Crud extend set_relation() function?

Tags: codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

Is there anyone knows how to extend the `set_relation()` ?

Here is the idea, base on the example of Grocery Crud employee and offices table[image: sample table]

```
$crud->set_relation('officeCode','offices','city');
```

the code output will show all city in dropdown, but I want to extent the `set_relation()` to filter all city by state to show in dropdown?

for example I want to show all city of Arizona state in dropdown, Does anyone done this before using grocery crud?

reference example:

[Grocery Crud](http://www.grocerycrud.com/crud/example/set_a_relation#!prettyPhoto%5Biframe%5D/0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
function employees_management()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_theme('datatables');
    $crud->set_table('employees');
    // add this line
    $crud->callback_edit_field('officeCode',array($this,'_call_back_offices'));
    $crud->callback_add_field('officeCode',array($this,'_call_back_offices'));

    $crud->display_as('officeCode','Office City');
    $crud->set_subject('Employee');

    $crud->set_relation('officeCode','offices','city');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}

function _call_back_offices()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model'); // your model
    $data = $this->user_model->getYou('offices','officeCode, city', "state = '".$this->session->userdata('state')."'"); // iam using session here
    $hasil ='<select name="officeCode">';
    foreach($data as $x)
    {
        $hasil .='<option value="'.$x->officeCode.'">'.$x->city.'</option>';
    }
    return $hasil.'</select>';
}

example user_model code:

function getYou($tabel,$field = '*', $cond ='')
{
    $this->db->select($field);
    $this->db->from($tabel);
    if(!empty($cond)) $this->db->where($cond);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know my response is some what dated and probably no use to the OP now, but I'm guessing there are many people who might be looking at this post for inspiration to their own set_relation problems. I propose a more simple solution to this... (in fairness to Idham I don't know when the 4th param of set_relation() became available.)

```
...
$state = "AZ"; // or however you get the state you want to filter by
$crud->set_relation('officeCode','offices','city', 'officeCode IN (SELECT officeCode FROM offices WHERE state='.$state.')');
...
```

Voila! True grocery_CRUD awesomeness!

Answer (score 4):

```
$crud->set_relation('officeCode','offices','city',array('country' => 'Arizona'));
```

This works fine as for version v.1.2 or later

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you'll be looking for is here --> http://www.grocerycrud.com/crud/function_name/set_model

This will allow you extend the functionality of grocery CRUD in the manner you want.
I haven't actually ventured to create my own custom functionality, but that's the manner in which you'll want to do it.